# Can't delete files in VS 2015 Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I have a normal VS 2015 Setup project (installed the extension, so it looks like the Setup projects of VS 2010 and older).

In the 'File System on Target Machine' section, I've added a folder "MyAppFolder" and then added the primary output of one of the projects of the solution. VS then added a bunch of dll's as well.

However, when I try to delete the folder it says:

> Cannot delete folder. Folder is not empty or it might contain excluded
>   files, which are not shown.

Well yes, it is not empty. If I right-click on a single dll file, the "Delete" option is disabled.

I don't want this folder to be installed on the target machine. How do I get rid of this folder in my setup project?

Comment: You may need to explain this a little more, because if you don't want the folder+files to be installed on the target machine then just don't add the folder and the project output to the setup project. You are explicitly installing the folder and files than saying you don't want to, that's the contradiction.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. Let me rather say that I wanted the folder, but don't want it anymore, but now I can't delete it out of the setup project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported way to delete files from an installation that are no longer needed (for example, because they were used in a custom action) is to set the component id to null.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

See remarks about Component Id.

There is no support for this in Visual Studio setups, so it's typically done manually by editing the MSI file with a tool such as Orca.

In general I think you always need to delete the individual files before deleting the folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and that's what worked for me:

1. Delete files inside the folders first.
2. There will be files can't be deleted, exclude them from the Project "Detected Dependencies" and try again.
3. Delete the parent folder.

Comment: This worked for me partially: I could not delete the parent folder (using VS2017) :an error popped up that there might be dependencies that were excluded and so not shown...
so I included them again and had to cut each of them and paste them in the "Application Folder". That finally got my "User's Desktop" parent folder empty...

Comment: This was useful in finding where the actual dependency was residing. 

Initially I created all my project files into root folder (Program Files), which was not right, so I created sub folder structure for my application and then moved the DLLs to the new directory by dragging but they were copied to new folder not moved. That's where the deletion of those files from root folder was disabled.

So I removed the DLLs from the new directory first and then the root folder files automatically vanished. This may be a bug. 

I use VS 2022.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a large number of data files and their associated folders. There were 64 folders and more than 1000 files. This is the solution I found:-

Removing Data Files

1. Fully expand the Installation Project in the Solution Explorer view in the left-hand pane until all the files being copied in the installation are listed
2. Select all the files you wish to delete (in my case all)
3. Select Edit->Remove from the Main Menu to remove all the files from the installation
4. Go to the File System view and delete their containing folders one-by-one.

Using this method, I managed to remove >1000 files and their folders in less than 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having this issue today and discovered a possible explanation. If you have output for a project in any part of the installer such that the .dlls that were added automatically by Visual Studio are referenced by said project, Visual Studio will not let you delete the references. If you were to delete this project output reference from your installer the .dlls will disappear as well. You can then re-add your output reference where you actually need it. So, to recap:

- Delete all project outputs which may reference the .dll (yes even ones in other locations)
- The automatically added .dlls should disappear
- Add the project outputs back in where you want them